# Why does select dropdown show empty default in Angular 8 after http call?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have written a basic html to display array elements in drop down, while default value to be shown is fetched from an http service in ngOnInit. But i get to see the default value in drop down as empty value.

This is my Html:

```
<select class="form-control" name="chocolate"
   [(ngModel)]="selectedChocolateId">
   <option *ngFor="let chocolate of chocolates" [ngValue]="chocolate.id">
   {{chocolate.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

And this is my Typescript code:

```
public selectedChocolateId:number;

ngOnInit() {
    this._chocolateService.GetChocolateId().subscribe(data => {
        this.selectedChocolateId = data;
    })
  }

public chocolates = [
  { id:1, "name":"Diary Milk"},
  { id:2, "name":"Five star"}
];
```

When i run the code, i get an empty default value in drop down. But when i console log, i get to see the fetched value from service. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably data is not of type number and therefore it cant find the right value.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twhj6x

Just add a `Number()` around data

Comment: That was the one! I'd get it as string from the server. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with object with select.Model bindings are not working properly, in order to fix this issue angular   supports [compareWith](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection) input. which takes function as a value. compareFn function that tells Angular how to compare the values.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
 <select [compareWith]="compareFn" class="form-control" name="chocolate"
       [(ngModel)]="selectedChocolateId">
       <option *ngFor="let chocolate of chocolates" [ngValue]="chocolate.id">
       {{chocolate.name}}
       </option>
    </select>
```

**component.ts**

```
compareFn(c1, c2): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```